# How to create a google map block to display number of nodes for a content type

Tags: google-maps

I have a content type "Houses".

I added 3 nodes as follows.

- Node 1 for county X and state A
- Node 2 for county X and state A
- Node 3 for county Y and state B.

I like to create a google map block which will show 2 in County X in google map and 1 in County Y section in google map.

Below is an example

[Google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tp19VIDwSJY-pD6rCBQ2viEKhUPtmad-VkXC1HRViQY/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Update 1

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q9uLBQpWY_a3du6HbWH3s0Gz2k_F4gJDYQDpeX9mcaw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Geofield_map](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield_map) module:

> Geofield Map is an advanced, complete and easy-to-use Geo Mapping
>   solution for Drupal 8, based on and fully compatible with the Geofield
>   module, that lets you manage the Geofield with an interactive Map both
>   in back-end and in the front-end.
>
> It represents the perfect solution to:
>
> geolocate (with one or more Locations / Geofields) any fieldable
>   Drupal entity throughout an Interactive Geofield Map widget; render
>   each Content's Locations throughout a fully customizable Interactive
>   Geofield Map Formatter; expose and query Contents throughout fully
>   customizable Map Views Integration; implement advanced front-end
>   Google Maps with Marker Icon & Infowindow advanced customizations,
>   custom Google Map Styles and Marker Clustering capabilities; customize
>   Map Geometries properties (Lines & Polylines, Polygons, Multipolygons,
>   etc.), based on Google Maps Polygons APIs;

[Take a look at Demo](http://www.geodemocracy.com/geofield_d8/web/).

So, in summary, you need to install this module and add it to your content type.
then with creating a custom view, you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. I heard that I need to have paid google cloud account in order to have that type of google map. I will search on it.

Comment: @GreenTree no problem. for a specified amount requests per day, it's free but in high requests, you should pay. let me know who it goes with you. because question is about the solution.

Comment: Thanks again! I have an example map. I am trying to follow the steps. It seems to me I am stuck. I am still researching. If we could chat in a chat group, it will help. Please see the google drive link above.  Thanks!

Comment: I got the API from this page. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key.  I get error when I use the API "This API project is not authorized to use this API.". I guess this API is not allowed to get the geocoding coordinates? Is there any free google API to get the geocoding coordinates?

Comment: @GreenTree, I guess you can create a google API key, but there will be some limitation on number of requests per day for that in free mode usage.